# docker-compose node js module not found after installing new module

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have this docker images that were perfectly running up until I had to add a new npm package to the node.js app and right after, the newly added module is "not found". I thought maybe the package is not good, so I tried with another to the same result ( not found ). These are my files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  builditjobs:
    container_name: 'BIJ-API'
    build: .
    ports:
      - '12100:12100'
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - './api:/var/apps/BIJ' #  Mount the local directory to the image so we don't have to restart our image to get new code
      - node_modules:/var/apps/BIJ/node_modules
  db:
    container_name: 'DB'
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*******
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bij
      - MYSQL_USER=bij
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=******
  admin:
    container_name: 'ADMINER'
    image: adminer
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
volumes:
  db-data:
  node_modules:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10
RUN mkdir -p /var/apps/BIJ
WORKDIR /var/apps/BIJ
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wait-for-it
RUN npm i npm@latest -g
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN pm2 ls
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --no-optional && npm cache clean -f
RUN chown -R node:node /var/apps/BIJ
RUN ls -la
EXPOSE 12100
ENTRYPOINT ./docker-entrypoint.sh
```

**docker-entrypoint:**

```
#!/bin/bash
wait-for-it db:3306 -- pm2 start ecosystem.config.js && pm2 logs API-1.0.0 --raw
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "bij-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "BIJ API",
  "main": "server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "CD",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@setreflex/logger": "^1.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.11",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mariadb": "^2.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "schema-inspector": "^1.6.9"
  }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong? I emphasise : it was working perfectly fine until I did a 
`npm i crypto-js -s`
and rebuilt image. Thanks!

LE: this is the exact error I get:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
BIJ-API        |     throw err;
BIJ-API        |     ^
BIJ-API        | 
BIJ-API        | Error: Cannot find module 'crypto-js'
BIJ-API        |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
BIJ-API        |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
BIJ-API        |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
BIJ-API        |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

Comment: Since the `node_modules` volume contains potentially valuable user data, Docker will never update it.  If you delete the `volumes:` block entirely, you will run the code that's actually built into the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the comment. It did point me to a working solution: I deleted the volumes and on rebuilt it works. So kudos for this! Question: is there a way to update node_modules inside the volumes without actually deleting/rebuilding it?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to install the dependencies(node_modules) each and every time u build it.

The Dockerfile is as follows...

`FROM node:12.3.1
WORKDIR /www/api
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN npm install babel-cli -g
ADD package.json /www/api
RUN npm install
ADD . /www/api
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

while the compose file is

```
api:
    build: .
    entrypoint:
        - /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"`
```

and then u could add a .dockerignore to ignore the node modules